# Clustered Index Vs Non-Clustered Index Usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, database-indexes

I am new to query optimization in T-SQL and I am a bit confused with one of the implementations.

The scenario has been explained here: I have this table (Table A) on which regular inserts are happening, no updates - only inserts as data is being moved to another table (Table B) based on a filter on a particular column in Table A (Col-1).

Two columns in Table A which I am focusing on are Col-1 (identity column) and Col-2 (`nvarchar(20)` -- and has duplicates).

Col-2 is on which I am filtering my records when moving my data from Table A to Table B.

Should I be defining a clustered index on Col-1 and a nonclustered index on Col-2, since I am filtering on Col-2; or should I only define a nonclustered index on Col-2 to speed up query performance?

Or should I keep the table as Heap and only define nonclustered index on the Col-2.

Moreover, would defining a clustered index and storing the table as a B-Tree degrade performance as we are appending data into Table -A weekly through inserts.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This depends on volume and the number of different values in col2.  Please provide more information.

Comment: There is no general answer to this kind of questions.  Different index designs will have different tradeoffs.  You'll have to experiment with different designs to find the best one for your workload.  And you generally don't make these decisions up-front.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : The volumne of the data keep on increasing weekly,as of now there are 50k records,The values in col2 values categorizing row groups.For example ,first 200 rows would have a value 'Row Group 1' and next 200 might have 'Row Group 2' and so on,col-2 is just a metric used to categorize rows.

Comment: As long as you don't have a clustered index - then your table is a **heap** - which is the equivalent of a streaming pile of data .... heaps are notoriously slow and "kludgy" - so having a **good**, well-chosen clustered index makes a lot of sense. [As Kimberly Tripp - the Queen of Indexing](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) shows - a well-chosen clustered index actually even speeds up insert and updates (all the time - or at least most of the time) - so that's always a good idea to have!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft : This needs to be done in Production so a bit sceptical about experimenting,but even i think thats the way to go ahead.

Comment: If you can't create a realistic test scenario outside of production, that's the first thing you need to fix.

Comment: What I would try first is an unique composite clustered index on (Col2, Col1), please note that Col2 is the first column in the index key. I'm very confident it would provide you great performace in your scenario. It would slightly degrade insert performance and you need to measure it to figure out if it was worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many here have said, it's hard to say definitively what will be the best solution without testing.  However, you say that you are filtering by col2 before choosing to move data.  Depending on what percentage of those records are moved, I would suggest starting with clustering on the unique col1.  Then create a non-clustered index on col2.  One advantage of the non-clustered index is that you can make it a filtered index with a WHERE clause.  So, for example, if only 10% of your records have a col2 value from a few choices that you care about, the index 'WHERE col2 IN (val, val2, val3) will be 10x smaller and therefore faster to access.

If you go this route, make sure the WHERE clause in your SELECT matches the WHERE clause you specify on the index.

Comment: Thats the index strategy that i have already implemented,the only thing that i have not implemented from what you have suggested are Filtered Indexes since the value passed into the where clause is a variable and i dont think it can be added to the filtered index,but would still checkout  filtered index  and if they can have a usage in this scenario